# Can we set another package id in app gradle file in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase-authentication, package

I came up with very interesting scenario which arise practically in my work life, so I need clarification here.

I have an android app uploaded in playstore from past 5 years with package name **com.xyz.org**.
Firebase crashlytics, Facebook integration, Push notification and other 3rd API's are integrated under this package id.

Now one of my client asked to, take separate package id as **com.pqr.org** and configure it in your app gradle as different build variant and generate seperate release build for him with new **jks file and credential** and upload it in separate play store account.

1. Is this possible to do ?
2. If yes then how to set it in app gradle file and change design based on package id ?
3. Will firebase and other 3rd party library will work or not ?
4. What other challenges I will face on cloning a project with different package id.

Help me on this. Thanks

Comment: You don't need to clone the project, just add a new flavor with a different packageName and make all changes in this flavor. I am not sure if Googly will reject an identical app that is uploaded twice with just a different packageName especially when you plan to use two different PlayStore developer accounts for uploading.

Comment: Ok after adding new flavor with a different packageName, while creating release build need to create new jks file and credential and upload to new developer account.

But I am also thinking about the versionCode, because the current **com.xyz.org** app version has reached to version 10 and new app **com.pqr.com** version need start from version 1.

Can you share some sample link for all this new build and flavor setup ??

Comment: Have you read https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants and https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ProductFlavor?

Comment: Thanks for your advice and useful link. I am able to set the different product flavor for my app. But as **com.xyz.org Java Keystore File (jks)** is already generated fir this package. Since I setup new package **com.pqr.com** package in my build gradle, do I need to create another **Java Keystore file (jks)** for this package id. ??

Comment: Signing keys should be totally independent from the app package names.

Comment: I didn't get your part. You mean to say I should create new **jks** file for **com.pqr.com** package name ??

Comment: I said it doesn't matter which key you use for which packageName. Only if you upload it to Google (the keys are thus an uploading key) you have to make sure the key is correctly registered as uploading key at Google.

Comment: ok Thanks and appreciate your so much help.